# How do get the full command line in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How do I get the full command line in ruby?

```
$ rails c
> $0 
=> "script/rails"
> ARGV
[]
> `ps -eo "%p|$|%a" | grep '^\\s*#{Process.pid}'`.strip.split("|$|")[1]
=> "/home/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf/bin/ruby script/rails console"
```

Is there anything cleaner than ninja ps I can do to get the same results?

To clarify, in case there is confusion, I want the exact same output as:

```
`ps -eo "%p|$|%a" | grep '^\\s*#{Process.pid}'`.strip.split("|$|")[1]
```

ARGV is coming back blank.
$0 is missing the full path.

Comment: You ask about a full command in Ruby, but then say Rails in your example. Which is it? Both have "command-lines" but they are very different application layers. And, what do you mean by "full command-line"? A sh/bash/zsh prompt?

Comment: @theTinMan did you read and run the sample I provided? I want `ps -eo "%a"` for my current ruby process.

Comment: You say "`rails c`" which is a Rails command line. `ps` anything is only going to return a running process, not a command line. Neither is going to "return" a command-line. `rails c` is based on IRB, and neither are a full "command-line". They're interactive shells inside Ruby, or Ruby with Rails' extensions loaded.

Comment: see screenshot http://cdn.discourse.org/uploads/meta_discourse/314/b89892bb3a2b4154.png

Comment: @theTinMan you seem to be focused on the words "command line" I have no idea what to call this. Does "full path of current process with trailing params that were passed in" work better for you?

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense, and, as such, it's not a Ruby question as much as it's an OS question since the majority of it occurs in the sub-shell.

Comment: Is reading `/proc/pid/cmdline` out of the question?

Comment: @TimPost it may work, but very close to my current hack anyway.

Comment: @SamSaffron Well, it beats a sub process full of pipe sorcery, but yeah - it would be fundamentally the same thing, just eliminating the middle man.

Comment: Reading `/proc/pid/cmdline` still requires figuring out the PID of the app, and, unless Ruby launched it, that is going to take iterating through all the files in `/proc` or filtering out `ps` output. Won't it? To me it's then "six of one, half-dozen of the other".

Answer (score 6):

I'd use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "Process ID: #{ $$ }"
puts `ps axw`.split("\n").select{ |ps| ps[ /\A#{ $$ }/ ] }
```

Running that inside a script outputs:

```
18222 s000  S+     0:00.25 /Users/foo/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby /Users/foo/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p385/bin/rdebug /Users/foo/Desktop/test.rb
```

Comment: I follow, I guess this has never abstracted itself in to Process, gip pid / fork and spawn are unixism that have found themselves in core ruby